# How to get values from 'distinct' column?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ado.net

This might be simple one and also this has been answered before but I don't know how to look for the exact method.

-> Am having two list box in my form. One is for product name and other one is for Company name.

-> On page load, `Listbox1` will retrieve values from `database(Product name)`. Once item has been selected from `listbox1`, the respective company names should be fetched in `listbox2`.

**For eg** : Database name is Motor

Here is my table named as "Register" and it contains two columns they are,

```
Productname        Companyname

Car                 Bmw
Bike                Bmw
Car                 Honda
Bike                Honda
```

**My Question is**

I retrieved product name details into `listbox1`, here the thing is i don't want to repeat the same items, so I used Distinct like this,

```
Select Distinct Productname from Register
```

**Now if i select car from listbox 1 then the respective company names should be display in listbox2. But what am getting is only Honda on my listbox2 and am not getting BMW.**

I can guess these things are happening only because of 'Distinct'. But i don't know exactly how to do this. Hope am not confusing you.So any help would be more helpful to me and thanks in advance.

**Update**

```
select Companyname from Register where Productname='"+listbox1.selecteditem+"'
```

This is the query which is used to retrieve values into listbox2. I used datareader to read and get the values.

Comment: can you provide the query you are using to fetch Company Names?

Comment: I have added the query @VitapRamdevputra

Comment: Not that one, Provide the query you are using to retrieve the Company name when passing Product name,

Comment: @Guru See my updated question. I have added the query under the field of Update.

Comment: Krishy, There should be a Unique Value representing your products Something like Product Code, and same should be used in as foriegn key  for Company Name table, then only it is possible to retrieve uniquely for each product.

Comment: can you show us more about your table structures, is all columns showed? is there only one table?

Comment: @MohsenHeydari I have just updated about my table and database as you asked. I have only one table named as Register.

Comment: It's urgent now, anyone can solve this would me really helpful to me. I am totally stuck with this simple concept..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a table called database! with the structure of (Productname, Companyname)
Query to fetch Product names (on page load) is

```
Select Distinct Productname from database
```

When Selected Item changed on Listbox1 you need to run query bellow to fetch Company names and populate
Listbox2:

```
Select Distinct Companyname from database where UPPER(Productname)  = UPPER(Listbox1.selectedItem)
```

You need to investigate what is `Listbox1.selectedItem` if you are getting some wired result.

Comment: I have tried this already. I can retrieve Honda, but am not getting BMW. I need to display all the companies which are linked with particular product name. I hope you understood now.

Comment: What is the value of Listbox1.selectedItem ?

Comment: As i mentioned above, i used distinct for retrieve values into listbox1. So i will have car and bike only. Here if i choose car, then the listbox2 should retrieve the companynames(BMW and Honda) whose matches with selected product name.

Comment: try using UPPER function as i updated the answer, let me know the result

Comment: I have tried by using ur method but it's not working. Still am getting only the last values i.e Honda only displaying.

Comment: dose running 'Select Distinct Companyname from database where UPPER(Productname)  = UPPER('Car')' directly in database results the value you want?

Comment: This won't be a better idea. Because i don't want only for specific product. I just gave an example, in my table am having more number of product names and company names are there. If i clear with this, i can do for all.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to my knowledge:
i) May be you are using Datareader(1) instead of start with datareader (0).
ii) try using datatable and check if you are getting all the values or not in the datatable object.
iii) Below code did work for me i tried placing both the columns(Product and company) in same table and with the below query..

```
"Select Distinct(Companyname) Company from DatabaseTable where Productname  = '"+Listbox1.selectedItem.text+"'";
```

ive got the output as you needed..